# Как совершить звонок через Asterisk с сервера на js?

Tags: node.js, asterisk, ari

Как инициировать звонок с сервера node.js и после подключить к звонку пользователя (браузер)?

Имеется настроенный Asterisk, где есть extension 666, который использует trunk провайдера.
Для задачи как я понял нужно использовать ARI [originate](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+16+Channels+REST+API#Asterisk16ChannelsRESTAPI-originate).

```js
axios.post(`.../ari/channels?endpoint=PJSIP/666&extension=8913*******&context=from-internal&priority=1&app=demoapp`);
```

На клиенте регистрирую пользователя через SIP.js

```js
const ua = new SIP.UserAgent({
    autoStart: true,
    transportOptions: {server: `wss://***`},
    authorizationUsername: '666',
    authorizationPassword: '***',
    uri: SIP.UserAgent.makeURI(`sip:666@$***`),
    delegate: {
        onInvite: (session) => {
            console.log('onInvite');
            session.accept();
        },
    },
});
const registerer = new SIP.Registerer(ua);
await registerer.register();
```

Ему прилетает invite, но по факту звонок на указанный номер не просиходит.

Что я делаю не правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Путем проб различных вариаций запроса нашел тот, который работает:

```
axios.post(`.../ari/channels?endpoint=PJSIP/8913******@rt-trunk&priority=1&app=demoapp`);
```

1. Номер телефона указывается не в параметре `extension`, в самом `endpoint`
2. Вместо extension с внутренним номером должен использоваться сам транк провайдера